# RStudio, knitr, pandoc, Word: how do I get a 'new page' in my docx?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, docx, pandoc

I am using the RStudio, knitr, pandoc, MS Word combo to get my final results in a `docx` document.

Occasionally, I would like the report to continue on a new page. I can't find the way to achieve this.

From what I have Googled, it seems to be possible with `CSS`. I don't know `HTML` or `CSS`, but if it is the solution I will learn. Just don't want to take the wrong road...

Comment: Page-break or "new page" is not supported by Pandoc, as it has no meaning in a bunch of document formats that Pandoc can convert to/from - although there are some ongoing discussions (again): https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/805

Comment: There has been some discussion about how to inject some XML in markdown to create docx pagebreaks with pandoc: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/FzLrhk0vVbU

Answer (score 2):

Try the LaTeX command \newpage. Pandoc recognizes it and might (not on a computer right now) translate it to a Word page break.

Comment: I forgot to state I was using markdown... Anyway I first tried \newpage on a line by itself and also between $ signs (as the markdown examples show usage of latex equations in this way), but neither worked... Thank you anyway

Comment: Interestingly, this works when converting to latex and then to pdf. Pandoc doesn't seem to escape the backslash so latex picks up the command. Even more interesting is that the \newpage gets erased when converting to some other format (e.g. HTML).

Comment: The new page in html not working makes sense though.  But also interested in new page and blank page for mobi and epub formats.

Answer (score 1):

````
​```{=openxml}
<w:p>
  </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
      <w:br w:type="page"/>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
​```
````

Insert this codes in the position of new page you wanted in the .RMD file, and knit the file to word file. It will be translated into a new page break by pandoc, just like a \newpage command using $Latex$.

Comment: [Edit] your answer to include an explanation of what this does and how it solves the problem